# Auto hide the "Load more" button inside tabbable

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a photo album page using bootstrap tabbable. In this page each tab holds rows of images, the first row was shown as default while other rows are hided. When pressing the "load more" button, one more row would be shown. Please check this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/ZE18Ad8WtS) for easy understanding.

My problem is that I don't know how to hide my "load more" button when all contents are shown. The problem is a bit complicated for me as I want to reset my tabs after every tab switching events.

My code:

HTML:

```
<div class="tabbable">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active" id="tab"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">tab1</a></li>
        <li id="tab"><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">tab2</a></li>
        <li id="tab"><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">tab3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="con-box">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
            <div>Row1-1</div>
            <div class="more" id="hidden1">Row1-2</div>
            <div class="more" id="hidden2">Row1-3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
            <div>Row2-1</div>
            <div class="more" id="hidden1">Row2-2</div>
            <div class="more" id="hidden2">Row2-3</div>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
            <div>Row3-1</div>
            <div class="more" id="hidden1">Row3-2</div>
            <div class="more" id="hidden2">Row3-3</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="loading"><a>Load more...</a></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var hidden = 1;
$("div.more").hide();

$(".loading").click(function(){
    $("div#hidden"+hidden).show();
    hidden++;
});

$("li#tab").click(function(){
    $("div.more").hide();
    hidden=1;
});
```

Comment: OT: the `id` should be unique!

Comment: Like @BeNdErR mentioned,  use unique IDs to avoid problems later.  This doesn't relate  to the problem you mentioned.

Comment: @BeNdErR Thanks for you reply. Should I try to define a unique prefix in the tabs, and get this prefix when the tab is select by user? How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed the approach a little.

- Every time you click the `load more` button, the code looks between the current tab hidden divs, and shows the first one.
- If the length of hidden divs (in the current tab page) is `<= 1`, then you have to hide the `.loading` button
- each time you change tab, you have to show the `.loading` button

*note that I've assigned an unique `id` to each `div.more`, but you can get rid of it as it is not used*

**Working example**: http://www.bootply.com/P5LGMtSuIW

**HTML**

```
<div class="tabbable">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">tab1</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">tab2</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">tab3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="con-box">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
            <div>Row1-1</div>
            <div class="more" id="t1-1">Row1-2</div>
            <div class="more" id="t1-2">Row1-3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
            <div>Row2-1</div>
            <div class="more" id="t2-1">Row2-2</div>
            <div class="more" id="t2-2">Row2-3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
            <div>Row3-1</div>
            <div class="more" id="t3-1">Row3-2</div>
            <div class="more" id="t3-2">Row3-3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="loading"><a>Load more...</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("div.more").hide();

$(".loading").click(function () {
    //--- get all divs
    var divs = $("div.tab-pane.active div.more:hidden");
    if (divs.length <= 1) $(".loading").hide();

    //--- show the first hidden
    $(divs).eq(0).show();
});

$("li.tab").click(function () {
    $(".loading").show();
    $("div.more").hide();
});
```

**CSS**

```
div.more{
    display:none;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I have updated the code.. Didn't notice that you had also duplicates between `li` `id`